# Issue with replacing negative values with zero

Tags: sql, case

Checked similar threads but no similar issues were experienced by other users.

The code does not seem to work and the error message says "Unexpected token 'Then' at line 11".

Lines 6 to 8 get the calculated column that determines the savings but if it is a loss, it becomes negative. I wanted to replace all negative values with 0 using Case but for some reason 'then' is treated as an error.

```
Select Distinct Reports.rptviewGovtTransparencyCode.project_title As Title,
  Reports.rptviewContract.AwardedDateTime As Awarded,
  Reports.rptviewContract.estimated_value As Budget,
  Convert(decimal,Replace(Reports.rptviewCustomFieldAnswer.Answer, ',',
  '')) As Value,
  Reports.rptviewContract.estimated_value -
  Convert(decimal,Replace(Reports.rptviewCustomFieldAnswer.Answer, ',',
  '')) As Saving,
  case when (Reports.rptviewContract.estimated_value -
  Convert(decimal,Replace(Reports.rptviewCustomFieldAnswer.Answer, ',', ''))
  <= 0 then 0) As Saving2
From Reports.rptviewGovtTransparencyCode
  Inner Join Reports.rptviewContract On Reports.rptviewContract.contract_id =
    Reports.rptviewGovtTransparencyCode.contract_id
  Inner Join Reports.rptviewCustomField On Reports.rptviewCustomField.OrgId =
    Reports.rptviewContract.OrgId
  Inner Join Reports.rptviewCustomFieldAnswer
    On Reports.rptviewCustomFieldAnswer.TargetAreaId =
    Reports.rptviewContract.project_id And Reports.rptviewCustomField.Id =
    Reports.rptviewCustomFieldAnswer.CustomFieldId
  Inner Join Reports.rptviewContractPrimaryContact
    On Reports.rptviewContract.contract_id =
    Reports.rptviewContractPrimaryContact.ContractId
Where Reports.rptviewGovtTransparencyCode.department = '1capital' And
  Reports.rptviewCustomField.Title = 'awarded value'
```

Comment: `case when then end` ... think you missing `end` part of your `case`

Comment: What end part is it if I may ask? I assumed that when (all that stuff) is less than or equal to zero, then the value should be 0. Am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Valdislave, Veljko89 is not talking about a logic error. The syntax of case is: case when <condition> then <expression> end. Notice the "end" at the end. You have to add "end" after the 0.

Comment: Thanks George Menoutis, now I understood and corrected the function. But sql still cannot be validated for some reason :(

Comment: @Veljko89 is a smart man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
case when (Reports.rptviewContract.estimated_value -
  Convert(decimal,Replace(Reports.rptviewCustomFieldAnswer.Answer, ',', ''))
  <= 0 then 0)
```

is missing the case's end, and also has a wrong parenthesis couple enclosing both the coondition and the "then" after the when clause. Replace it with the following:

```
case when Reports.rptviewContract.estimated_value -
  Convert(decimal,Replace(Reports.rptviewCustomFieldAnswer.Answer, ',', ''))
  <= 0 then 0 end
```

In order to demonstrate better, what you had before was:

```
case when (condition then result)
```

while the correct was

```
case when condition then result end
```

You shall not p...hide the "then" inside the parenthesis: the "when" cannot see it.

Comment: Thank you for correcting, did not realised that 'end' is needed. I have now added it but after refreshing, the error still stops at 'then', naming it 'Unexpected Token'

Comment: Upd. Also tried to replace 'end' with 'else' and the original subtraction formula. But the validation still stops at 'then'

Comment: I updated the answer, try again, you have to get rid of the parentheses too.

Comment: No idea what was changed but magic worked, thank you very much indeed! I also added the original formula after 'else' to make sure positive values also come back but your advice was invaluable!

Comment: I updated the answer so you can understand and not believe it was magic :)